# how to pass different $results from controller to view page in codeigniter?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I put a condition for displaying different results in view page.I want to pass these six diffrent result arrays in view page.I tried this.but it did nt work.pls help.

Controller

```
$m1=date('F');
$y1=date('Y');
$result['credit']=$this->money_m->gettotcredit($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['loan']=$this->money_m->gettotloan($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['bank']=$this->money_m->gettotbank($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['insurance']=$this->money_m->gettotinsurance($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['mutualfund']=$this->money_m->gettotmutualfund($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['fdbonds']=$this->money_m->gettotfdbonds($uid,$m1,$y1);
        $result['assestliab']=array_unique( $result['credit'],$result['loan'],$result['bank'],$result['insurance'],$result['mutualfund'],$result['fdbonds']);
    $this->load->view('mainpage2',$result);

I want to take each result 

        foreach($credit as $cr)
        {

        .......
        }
    etc
```

Comment: post full code as well

Comment: Why you use the array_unique function in controller ?

Comment: how will join this results

Comment: add more spesific code please, all of that function maybe

Answer (score 1):

try like this

> **When you pass data from controller to view use `$data`. Its good practice.**

**In Controller**

```
$data['credit'] = # some function 
$data['loan'] = # another function

$this->load->view('mainpage2',$data);
```

**In View**

```
foreach ($credit as $value) {
    echo $value['creditVariable'];
}

foreach ($loan as $value) {
    echo $value['loanVariable'];
}
```

---

**In Your case**

```
$m1=date('F');
$y1=date('Y');

$result['credit']=$this->money_m->gettotcredit($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['loan']=$this->money_m->gettotloan($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['bank']=$this->money_m->gettotbank($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['insurance']=$this->money_m->gettotinsurance($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['mutualfund']=$this->money_m->gettotmutualfund($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['fdbonds']=$this->money_m->gettotfdbonds($uid,$m1,$y1);
# remove this line $result['assestliab']=array_unique( $result['credit'],$result['loan'],$result['bank'],$result['insurance'],$result['mutualfund'],$result['fdbonds']);


$this->load->view('mainpage2',$result);
```

**In view**

```
foreach ($credit as $value) {
    echo $value['creditVariable'];
}

foreach ($loan as $value) {
    echo $value['loanVariable'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This format of pass controller value to View file

**Controller**

```
$m1=date('F');
$y1=date('Y');
$result['credit']=$this->money_m->gettotcredit($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['loan']=$this->money_m->gettotloan($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['bank']=$this->money_m->gettotbank($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['insurance']=$this->money_m->gettotinsurance($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['mutualfund']=$this->money_m->gettotmutualfund($uid,$m1,$y1);
$result['fdbonds']=$this->money_m->gettotfdbonds($uid,$m1,$y1);
$this->load->view('mainpage2',$result);
```

**View**

```
if(isset($credit)) {

foreach($credit as $result) {

......
......

}

}
```